# Помогите пожалуйста реализовать функцию по преобразованию матрицы, думал

Tags: c++, матрицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал, нужно сделать просто из матрицы треугольную, но ошибся, теперь не понимаю как реализовать

Помогите, пожалуйста, вот мой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printTriangularMatrix(int arr[3][4]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j >= i) {
                std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "0 ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int lesscounter(int arr[3][4], int num) {
    int count = 0;
    int sum = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ((sum / 4) < num)
            count += 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            sum += arr[i][j];
    }
    return count;
}


int main() {
    int matrix[3][4] = { {-2, 0, 4, 7},
                          {6, -8, 0, 5},
                          {0, -3, 4, 1} };

    cout << "Enter matrix";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Complete matrix" << endl;

    printTriangularMatrix(matrix);

    cout << lesscounter(matrix, 1);
    return 0;
}
```